# UILongPressGestureRecognizer don't work after the use of a UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

When my hitView comes partially from the superview after a UIPanGestureRecognizer, the UILongPressGestureRecognizer don't work. Why?

```
   - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
    {
      UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pan:)];
    [panGesture setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panGesture setDelegate:self];
    [_glassesImage addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];


    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(enchance:)];
    longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.2;
    [_glassesImage addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];


    [self addSubview:_glassesImage];
    }



    - (void)enchance:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
   {
        UIView *hitView = [gestureRecognizer view];
        hitView.alpha=0.6;
        inLongPress=YES;
        gestureRecognizer.allowableMovement = 200;

      if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        hitView.alpha=1.0;
        inLongPress=NO;

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try defining a delegate for your gesture recognizers and then provide an implementation for:

```
 - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

([refs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer%3ashouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer%3a))

```
 - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return YES;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add delegate to longPressGesture.

```
longPressGesture.delegate = self;
```

I think it will be helpful to you.